# How to bring M.C. Escher to actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, geometry, hyperbolic-function

I need a bit of counseling. I´m trying to reproduce one of M.C. Escher´s models in Actionscript, but I´m not entirely sure about where to begin. Ideally, I´d want to make something from his [Circle Limit](https://www.google.com.ec/search?q=escher%20circle%20limit&client=firefox-a&hs=1A0&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=sb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=cl5mU8KGHO3JsQT40oEQ&ved=0CCwQsAQ&biw=1600&bih=758) series look somewhat like this: http://vimeo.com/4154382

Could anyone provide any pointers as in what approach should I take? I am not an expert coder, so anything would help.

Thanks in advance,

Garfeel M.D.

Comment: There are many ways to display content on the screen with Flash. Be it Vector art from assets, drawing them with primitive functions like lineTo(x,y), displaying drawn/generated bitmaps. To help you it would be nice to hear what exactly you want to achieve. Is there a math formula that you need to implement in code? Also, for performance reasons you might need to use the illusion of this, not the real thing since drawing so much vector is probably impossible for CPU to handle if you try to animate it. With Bitmaps it could be done.

Comment: Mr. Creative Magic, you are absolutely right. Perhaps an illusion is the best way to go. My intent is to create a visual display, so as long as it looks like an hyperbolic tessellation, it will do just fine. I do not need to use any particular formula, actually, I am yet to find a formula that would allow me to  create this visual display.

Answer (score 1):

The different copies of a hyperbolic transformation are related to one another via [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) which leave the circle fixed. You can represent them as transformations

```
       (a+bi)z + (c+di)
z |->  ----------------
       (c-di)z + (a-bi)
```

You might want to represent the switch from circle to half plane as a Möbius transformation as well, to avoid numeric issues with simple zooming.

I have tools available to make hyperbolic ornaments from Escher ornaments, and zoom into them in real time. But Escher isn't public domain yet, and in my experience the Escher foundation is less than enthusiastic in granting permission for derived works. So if you get ther OK, or decide on some other artist (possibly starting from a Euclidean ornament), feel free to contact me by e-mail to discuss this further.

I recently was a jury member foir [an ornament competition](http://www.spektrum.de/alias/dachzeile/ornament-wettbewerb/1223589) where [some submissions](http://www.spektrum.de/alias/ornament/ornament-21-2-2014/1235512) were hyperbolized from Euclidean drawings. Gaining permissions for those would likely be easier than from the Escher foundation.

Comment: MvG, 
Thanks a lot for your reply. I didn´t realize that Escher´s models will bring up copyright issues. But, if that´s the case, it would be perfectly fine for me to use another hyperbolic tessellation or, if I was able to, create one myself. 
I would love to discuss this further with you, may I have your email address?
Gratitude,